# unable to Capture Jstl loop variable in JSP var

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3, jstl

I am unable to capture jstl loop variable in the jsp var to use for google maps markers but i am able to print that values on the jsp page

```
var markers = [
           <c:forEach var="s" items="${list.rows}">
[<c:out value="${s.latitude}"/>,<c:out value="${s.longitude}"/>]
        </c:forEach>        ];
```

but it seems var markers is not capturing that jstl variable. Any ideas??

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 1):

i guess the better way is to do like below ,
Intialize an array variable

```
var markers= new Array();    
           <c:forEach var="s" items="${list.rows}">
markers.push(${s.latitude})
markers.push(${s.longitude})
        </c:forEach>
```

And push it into the array using `.push` method . make it simple using EL

Comment: Thanks krish for answer, but i need that lat long values in the varible as comma separated as below var = [23.5,56.6] any suggestions?

Comment: @shyamkumarArshid just combine push lines to a single one like `markers.push("'"+${s.latitude}+","+${s.longitude}+"'")`

Comment: @shyamkumarArshid you could try [`<fmt:parseNumber>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_parsenumber_tag.htm) to format values

Comment: Still No luck Guys. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to print ${list} to see if it has values. Just to check that the problem is not at server end.